# How to enable scrolling in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a login page. Its fixed now, but I want to enable scroll when I focus on any of one text box. How to do it?

```
 <ion-view>

<ion-content class="background">
    <div class="loginscreen">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-80 col-offset-10">

                <div class="appheader-frame">
                    <span>
          <img src="img/clock.png" alt="clock" class="clockwidth"></img>
        </span>
                    <h1 class="timesheettext">
          <b>Timesheet Tracking</b>
        </h1>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class=" formpadding col-80  col-offset-10">
                <form novalidate name="loginForm" ng-submit="doLogin(loginForm)">
                    <label class="item item-input labelusername">
                        <i class="icon  placeholder-icon"><img src="img/user.png" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;"/></i>
                        <input name="UserName" type="text" ng-model="User.UserName" placeholder="Username or Email" ng-focus="hidefooter()" required>
                    </label>
                    <p ng-show="loginForm.UserName.$error.required && loginSubmitted" class="usernameerror">
                        Please provide username
                    </p>
                    <label class="item item-input labelpassword">
                        <i class="icon  placeholder-icon"><img src="img/password.png" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;"/></i>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="User.Password" placeholder="Password" ng-focus="hidefooter()" required>
                    </label>
                    <p ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required && loginSubmitted" class="usernameerror">
                        provide Password
                    </p>
                    <p ng-show="myflag">
                        wrong credentials
                    </p>

                    <button class="button button-block button-lightgreen" type="submit">
                        <p class="login">
                            <b>submit</b>
                        </p>
                    </button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-inherit myfooter hide-on-keyboard-open">
        <div class="title">
            <p id="footer" class="byxyz" ng-show=footerflag>By xyz Software Pvt Ltd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Is that possible in ionic framework? Then how to do it? Please explain.And don't remove anything in the page and don't add anymore details to make it scroll.I simply want to enable scroll in it but  the page should be same as it is right now

Answer (score 3):

simply added **overflow-scroll="false"** in ion-content.

```
  <ion-content class="background" overflow-scroll="false" >
       //code

  </ion-content>
```